# Xamarin.Forms Bluetooth Interface choices

Tags: dependency-injection, interface, xamarin.android, android-bluetooth, xamarin.uwp

I am attempting to write dependency injection  methods, with an interface, so that I would be able to really have a single user interface for both Android and UWP.

Processing and testing one feature at a time. The schema is working, but my problem is that on the UWP side, most functions are asynchrone, while they are not on Android.

So my question is, should I "fake" async functions on the android side, and if yes, how?

Here is my example:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace XamarinBTArduinoLed
{
    public interface IBlueTooth
    {
        // as a first test, I will try to get a list of paired devices in both Android and UWP
        List<string> PairedDevices();
    }
}
```

This works with Android, but for UWP, it would need to be

```
public interface IBlueTooth
    {
        // as a first test, I will try to get a list of paired devices in both Android and UWP
        Task<List<string>> PairedDevices();
    }
```

Which does not work for my current Android implementation. So, how should I modify this, to "fake" an asynchrone method, assuming it would be the best choice? Or is there any other way I am not thinking about?

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(XamarinBTArduinoLed.Droid.BlueToothInterface))]
    namespace XamarinBTArduinoLed.Droid
    {

        public class BlueToothInterface : IBlueTooth
        {       
            public List<string> PairedDevices()
            {
                List<string> BTItems = new List<string>();

                BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter;
                if (adapter == null) throw new Exception("No BlueTooth Adapter Found.");
                if (!adapter.IsEnabled)
                {
                    adapter.Enable();
                }
                //if (!adapter.IsEnabled)
                //{
                //    throw new Exception("BlueTooth adapter is NOT enabled.");
                //}
                foreach (var item in adapter.BondedDevices)
                {     

                    BTItems.Add(item.Name + " - " + item.Type.ToString());
                }
                return BTItems;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what seems to be the best way to go:

-1- I changed the interface to get a Task returned:

```
public interface IBlueTooth
    {
        // as a first test, I will try to get a list of paired devices in both Android and UWP
        Task<List<string>> PairedDevices();
    }
```

-2- I modified the Android implementation accordingly:

```
public Task<List<string>> PairedDevices()
        {
            List<string> BTItems = new List<string>();

            BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter;
            if (adapter == null) throw new Exception("No BlueTooth Adapter Found.");
            if (!adapter.IsEnabled)
            {
                adapter.Enable();
            }
            var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    foreach (var item in adapter.BondedDevices)
                    {

                        BTItems.Add(item.Name);
                    }
                    return BTItems;
                });
            return t;
        }
```

-3- I implemented INotifyPropertyChanged to display in XAML

This is now working perfectly, I get my list of USB/Serial devices from both Android and Windows UWP. Will certainly take a while to create the whole process for both platforms, but at least it looks like I am on a good start.

Don't hesitate if you have any comments, recommendations,maybe a better way.....